# Incorrect syntaxt near '='

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm using a SQL Server stored procedure but I'm getting a syntax error in SQL `Case`.

Here is my stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSelectServiceRequest]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        [id],
        [ServiceID],
        [fullName],
        [email], [mobile],
        [address],
        [serviceNeed],
        [problem],
        [serviceDate],
        [createdOn],
        [status] = CASE [status]
                      WHEN '1' THEN 'New Request'
                      WHEN '2' THEN 'Pending'
                      WHEN '3' THEN 'Accept By Provider'
                      ELSE 'Close'
                   END
    FROM 
        [tblBookingDetail]
    ORDER BY 
        [createdOn] DESC;
END;
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to assign a value to the `status` column? That won't work in a `SELECT` statement. Just remove the `status = ` part if you want to return a value based on the `status` column.

Comment: Syntax is OK, are you sure this is the full SP ?

Comment: #Ezlo yes its full SP.

Comment: Try writing the CASE statement again, you might have a weird character in your script. Also post the full error message you are getting.

Comment: problem has been solved as i was assigning the value into the status fiels i.e wrong. i just have the syntaxt and its working fine

Comment: @shamisheikh there is not status field to assign the value into, as it's a select and it's not a variable,nor an insert. The syntax you posted should work.

Comment: i dont know but some how it was not working and was giving a syntax error.
But thanks for your time and support now its working fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spSelectServiceRequest]
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            [id]
          , [ServiceID]
          , [fullName]
          , [email]
          , [mobile]
          , [address]
          , [serviceNeed]
          , [problem]
          , [serviceDate]
          , [createdOn]
          ,  CASE [status]
                           WHEN '1'
                           THEN 'New Request'
                           WHEN '2'
                           THEN 'Pending'
                           WHEN '3'
                           THEN 'Accept By Provider'
                           ELSE 'Close'
                       END AS [status]
        FROM [tblBookingDetail]
        ORDER BY 
            [createdOn] DESC;
    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

its minor syntax issue in your query:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spSelectServiceRequest]
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            [id]
          , [ServiceID]
          , [fullName]
          , [email]
          , [mobile]
          , [address]
          , [serviceNeed]
          , [problem]
          , [serviceDate]
          , [createdOn]
          , CASE [status]
                           WHEN '1'
                           THEN 'New Request'
                           WHEN '2'
                           THEN 'Pending'
                           WHEN '3'
                           THEN 'Accept By Provider'
                           ELSE 'Close'
                       END AS [Status]
        FROM [tblBookingDetail]
        ORDER BY 
            [createdOn] DESC;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ALTER PROC [dbo].[spSelectServiceRequest]
 AS
 BEGIN
    SELECT id
    ,ServiceID
    ,fullName
    ,email
    ,mobile
    ,address
    ,serviceNeed
    ,problem
    ,serviceDate
    ,createdOn
    ,CASE STATUS
        WHEN '1'
            THEN 'New Request'
        WHEN '2'
            THEN 'Pending'
        WHEN '3'
            THEN 'Accept By Provider'
        ELSE 'Close'
        END
     FROM tblBookingDetail
     ORDER BY createdOn DESC
 END
```

Try this. Hope it works.